# Adding a mailing list subscribe to contact form

Tags: plugins, plugin-contactform

Is there an existing plugin or a built-in way of adding an "add me to mailing list" button to a contact form? Not just that it gets stored in the database as a lightswitch, but so it actually subscribes them (or at least sends them a sign-up confirmation email)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a native way to to do that... it would have to be done with a plugin.

I'm not sure if there is an existing one, but [Straight Up Craft](http://straightupcraft.com/) currently has the most up-to-date list of available Craft plugins, so that would be a good starting point.

Answer (score 2):

The [MailChimp Subscribe](https://github.com/aelvan/mailchimp-subscribe-craft/) plugin might be the one you want.

Comment: Unfortunately that's only for subscribing. I'd need to send an email like a contact form, then off the back of that ALSO subscribe to a list

Comment: Daryl did you find a solution?